# scope of boost allocators: scratchpad for e.g. a frame or also long-lived?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, boost, qnx

I'm writing an application for the platform QNX. Deallocations there seem to be really slow. Even instructing the system to never release memory back to the kernel won't help much. It's faster, but still stays quite some time in the system (i.e. inside the call to C++'s delete).

I thought I could apply custom allocators to help reduce this stall.
I wrote a test where my use case is depicted: http://pastebin.com/x23aB8uj

The output on my linux laptop is this:

```
Running test_alloc ...
test_alloc took: 1.07227 ms.
Running dealloc ...
dealloc took: 0.0358887 ms.
Running test_custom_alloc_pool_1 ...
test_custom_alloc_pool_1 took: 1.70239 ms.
Running dealloc ...
dealloc took: 91.7312 ms.
Running test_custom_alloc_pool_2 ...
test_custom_alloc_pool_2 took: 0.78833 ms.
Running dealloc ...
dealloc took: 95.5864 ms.
```

That means, for a single deallocation almost a millisecond is needed (on my laptop. On QNX it's a couple of milliseconds).

In the example of `boost::singleton_pool` ([link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html#boost_pool.pool.interfaces.interfaces.singleton_pool)) after the malloc is stated:

*Do something with t; don't take the time to free() it.*

Does that mean my use-case just does not apply to the usage of these allocators, i.e. they should be used more for a temporary scratch-pad where you seldomly destroy objects?

Comment: Related, see [Custom heap allocators](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/125648) on Programmers.SE. I'm guessing its related to QNX and its C++ allocator or malloc, and not Boost.

Comment: @jww the test results are from my linux laptop, not from QNX. So deallocations are slow there as well when using pools. On QNX it's just even more slow.